# How to prevent macro redefinition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

After working some time on my project, this warning begins to appear:

```
2>Game.cpp
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\windef.h(126) : warning C4005: 'APIENTRY' : redefinición de macro
2>        c:\users\ferran\directo\gameprojects\dev-libs\glfw\include\glfw.h(72) : vea la definición anterior de 'APIENTRY'
2>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\wingdi.h(23) : warning C4005: 'WINGDIAPI' : redefinición de macro
2>        c:\users\ferran\directo\gameprojects\dev-libs\glfw\include\glfw.h(88) : vea la definición anterior de 'WINGDIAPI'
```

I'm sure that it's a matter of the order of the include files to solve, because none of these files are mine. My question is if there is a generic way to prevent this or to find which files must to be reordered to avoid this message.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error message itself is telling you the incorrect order. It says that `windef.h` and `wingdi.h` are redefining symbols that were defined in `glfw.h`.

Put `glfw.h` after the Windows include files.

Comment: That is a very good answer, because is a general solution or at least a good starting point to solve these type of problems.

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft doesn't generally design headers to be free-standing. Most of the Windows-oriented headers require that you have first included `<windows.h>`. Except for the dependency on that Mother Of All Headers, usually there are no specific header dependencies so by including `<windows.h>` first you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: There are exceptions, though. For example winsock2.h must be included first to prevent inclusion of winsock.h done from windows.h

Comment: @PawełStankowski: Thanks! That sounded to me like there must be some macro that controls the includes, so I fired up a Visual Studio (by accident 2012), which has a nice go-to-header feature. Oh, I see only two possibilities: using the internal include guard `_WINSOCKAPI_`, that's dirty, or using `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`. The latter is almost standard practice, so that should be good.

Comment: It's ok as a workaround, if you do not need any functionality behind lean&mean define or you are sure that your code will not be used from project that requires functionality from windows.h and is hidden by WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN define.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in the file *Game.cpp*. Try to include *windows.h* before *glfw.h*. There is a guard in *glfw.h* which will prevent that warning:

```
#ifndef APIENTRY
 #ifdef _WIN32
  #define APIENTRY __stdcall
 #else
  #define APIENTRY
 #endif
 #define GL_APIENTRY_DEFINED
#endif // APIENTRY
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately or fortunately, no. There is no such tool that automates it. You have to go read the code in those header files, figure out what is going on and take appropriate actions.

The most you can do is

1. Check if macro is defined using [`ifdef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a1b21sf%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) or [`if defined(...)` or `if !defined(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) preprocessor constructs.
2. Undefine macro using [`undef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4w8783%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Only ANSI C considers macro redefinition an error.

Comment: Read "macro replacement" chapter in both C99 and C11 stanard docs. Both say that macro should not be redefined unless replacement lists are identical. So I think you're wrong that it is not consider as an error. The truth is that most __compilers__ generate warning only, but this is their way of dealing with non-compiliant code.

Answer (score 2):

This may be caused by Visual Studio pre-compiling headers for you. Be sure that all standard and microsoft headers are included before yours.  Don't include microsoft headers in any of your .h files (it looks like you have windef.h and wingdi.h inlcuded in your glfw.h).  Be sure that all your headers are side-effect free.  The problem should then go away.  Figuring out exactly what is causing it is generally very hard.

Comment: FYI, glfw.h is an API for OpenGL. _No one_ can change APIs. :P