# GLFW, GLEW and "my class" issue

Tags: opengl, glew, glfw

I'm using `GLFW` (static linking library - `glfw.lib`) and `GLEW` in my project, but now I got a problem:
I write a simplest `GLFW` program (`glfwInit()`, `glfwOpenWindow()`, ..., `glewInit()`) which do nothing except open a black window, call `glewInit()` and main loop which contain only `glfwSwapBuffers()`, then it run Ok. But when I add a class (`cshader.h`, `cshader.cpp`) for load shaders (no specials in class, no static variables, no static method, haven't create any instances yet, so, I only drag and drop two files into Visual Studio work space window), then rebuild, and press `F5`, Visual Studio show `sfs.exe has triggered a breakpoint.` message and break at `msvcr110d.dll!_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(const void * pUserData) Line 2036 C++`.  But if I change to `Release` then it fine.

My call stack is:

```
msvcr110d.dll!_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(const void * pUserData) Line 2036  C++
msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1322   C++
msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1265  C++
msvcr110d.dll!free(void * pUserData) Line 49    C++
sfs.exe!__glfwPlatformWaitEvents()  Unknown
sfs.exe!__glfwPlatformWaitEvents()  Unknown
sfs.exe!__glfwPlatformOpenWindow()  Unknown
sfs.exe!_glfwOpenWindow()   Unknown
sfs.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line 54   C++
```

Yep, I have no ide about this problem, I haven't create any class instance yet, my class only have some methods for load shader, link program, use, release shader, set uniform. Can anyone help me this?

**Update:** My `cshader.h` and `cshader.cpp` are:

```
// cshader.h
#ifndef __CShader_h__
#define __CShader_h__

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <GL/gl.h>

class CShader
{
protected:
  GLuint m_FragmentShader;
  GLuint m_VertexShader;
  GLuint m_Program;

  bool readTextFile(const char *name, std::string& text);
  GLuint createShader(const char *name, GLenum type);

public:
  CShader();
  CShader(const char *vertex, const char *fragment);
  ~CShader();

  bool loadVertexShader(const char *vertex);
  bool loadFragmentShader(const char *fragment);
  bool link();
  void use();
  void end();
  GLint getUniformLocation(const char *name);
  GLint getAttribLocation(const char *name);
  void uni4x4Matrix(const char *name, float *matrix);
  void uni1i(const char *name, GLuint value);

  void enableAttrib(const char *name);
  void enableAttrib(GLint attrib);

  void disableAttrib(const char *name);
  void disableAttrib(GLint attrib);
};

#endif /* __CShader_h__ */


// cshader.cpp
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include "cshader.h"

bool CShader::readTextFile(const char *name, std::string& text) {
  std::ifstream in;

  in.open(name, std::ios::in);
  if (in.fail()) {
    std::cout << "CShader::readTextFile(\"" << name << "\") false" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  std::ostringstream data;
  data << in.rdbuf();
  text = data.str();
  in.close();

  return true;
}

GLuint CShader::createShader(const char *name, GLenum type) {
  std::string text, shader_type;
  const char *source;
  GLuint shader;

  switch(type) {
  case GL_VERTEX_SHADER:
    shader_type = "GL_VERTEX_SHADER";
    break;

  case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER:
    shader_type = "GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER";
    break;

  default:
    shader_type = "UNKNOW_SHADER";
  }

  if (!readTextFile(name, text)) return 0;
  source = text.c_str();

  shader = glCreateShader(type);
  glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, 0);
  glCompileShader(shader);

  GLint is_compiled;
  glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &is_compiled);
  if (GL_FALSE == is_compiled) {
    std::cout << "CShader::createShader(): Compile " << shader_type << " (" << name << ") error:" << std::endl;
    int errLen, errRet;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &errLen);

    char *errMsg = new char[errLen + 1];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, errLen, &errRet, errMsg);
    std::cout << errMsg << std::endl;
    delete [] errMsg;

    glDeleteShader(shader);
    return 0;
  }

  return shader;
}

CShader::CShader() {
  m_FragmentShader = 0;
  m_VertexShader = 0;
  m_Program = 0;
}

CShader::CShader(const char *vertex, const char *fragment) {
  m_FragmentShader = 0;
  m_VertexShader = 0;
  m_Program = 0;

  loadVertexShader(vertex);
  loadFragmentShader(fragment);
}

CShader::~CShader() {
  if (m_Program > 0) {
    glDetachShader(m_Program, m_VertexShader);
    glDetachShader(m_Program, m_FragmentShader);
    glDeleteProgram(m_Program);
  }

  if (m_VertexShader > 0) glDeleteShader(m_VertexShader);
  if (m_FragmentShader > 0) glDeleteShader(m_FragmentShader);
}

bool CShader::loadVertexShader(const char *vertex) {
  if (m_VertexShader > 0) glDeleteShader(m_VertexShader);

  m_VertexShader = createShader(vertex, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  return (m_VertexShader > 0) ? (true) : (false);
}

bool CShader::loadFragmentShader(const char *fragment) {
  if (m_FragmentShader > 0) glDeleteShader(m_FragmentShader);

  m_FragmentShader = createShader(fragment, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  return (m_FragmentShader > 0) ? (true) : (false);
}

bool CShader::link() {
  if (m_VertexShader <= 0 || m_FragmentShader <= 0) return false;
  if (m_Program > 0) {
    std::cout << "Program have already linked!" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  m_Program = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(m_Program, m_VertexShader);
  glAttachShader(m_Program, m_FragmentShader);
  glLinkProgram(m_Program);

  GLint is_Linked;
  glGetProgramiv(m_Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &is_Linked);
  if (GL_FALSE == is_Linked) {
    std::cout << "CShader::link() got error:" << std::endl;

    int errLen, errRet;
    glGetProgramiv(m_Program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &errLen);

    char * errMsg = new char[errLen + 1];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(m_Program, errLen, &errRet, errMsg);
    std::cout << errMsg << std::endl;
    delete [] errMsg;

    glDetachShader(m_Program, m_VertexShader);
    glDetachShader(m_Program, m_FragmentShader);
    glDeleteProgram(m_Program);
    m_Program = 0;
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

void CShader::use() {
  if (m_Program <= 0) {
    std::cout << "CShader::use(): Program not ready!" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  glUseProgram(m_Program);
}

void CShader::end() {
  glUseProgram(0);
}

GLint CShader::getUniformLocation(const char *name) {
  if (m_Program <= 0) return -1;
  return glGetUniformLocation(m_Program, name);
}

GLint CShader::getAttribLocation(const char *name) {
  if (m_Program <= 0) return -1;
  return glGetAttribLocation(m_Program, name);
}

void CShader::uni4x4Matrix(const char *name, float *matrix) {
  GLint matLoc = getUniformLocation(name);
  if (matLoc >= 0) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix);
  } else {
    std::cout << "CShader::uni4x4Matrix(): " << name << " uniform not found!" << std::endl;
  }
}

void CShader::uni1i(const char *name, GLuint value) {
  GLint matLoc = getUniformLocation(name);
  if (matLoc >= 0) {
    glUniform1i(matLoc, value);
  } else {
    std::cout << "CShader::uni1i(): " << name << " uniform not found!" << std::endl;
  }
}

void CShader::enableAttrib(const char *name) {
  GLint attribLoc = getAttribLocation(name);
  if (attribLoc < 0) {
    std::cout << "CShader::enableAttrib(): " << name << " attrib not found!" << std::endl;
  } else {
    enableAttrib(attribLoc);
  }
}

void CShader::enableAttrib(GLint attrib) {
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(attrib);
}

void CShader::disableAttrib(const char *name) {
  GLint attribLoc = getAttribLocation(name);
  if (attribLoc < 0) {
    std::cout << "CShader::disableAttrib(): " << name << " attrib not found!" << std::endl;
  } else {
    disableAttrib(attribLoc);
  }
}

void CShader::disableAttrib(GLint attrib) {
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(attrib);
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include "cshader.h"

#include <gl/glfw.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "glfw.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")

using namespace std;


void GLFWCALL reshape(int w, int h)
{
}

void display()
{

}

bool init()
{

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
        cout << "glfwInit() return false!" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_WINDOW_NO_RESIZE, GL_TRUE);
    if(glfwOpenWindow(640, 480, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 1, GLFW_WINDOW) != GL_TRUE) {
        cout << "Open window fail!" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        cout << "load opengl functions failed!" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetWindowTitle("Shadow from scratch...");
    if (!init()) {
        cout << "init() return false!" << endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(&reshape);
    reshape(640, 480);

    bool running = true;
    while (running) {
        display();
        glfwSwapBuffers();

        running = !glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

**Update 2:** I have changed to `glLoadGen` to load OpenGL extensions but the problem still here ...

Comment: Some source code would be nice. I had to send in my then defective crystal orb for maintenance some years ago and never got it back, because the defect still persists ;)

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks for quick reply, I have just update the codes, so, are you `glew` or `glfw` author?

Comment: This is really curious. Your class looks fine, no inhertance of something that could trigger weird tings. Something in glfwOpenWindow trips over an invalid pointer. Just a suggestion: GLFW is open source, so how about you compile it yourself, with debugging symbols, so that you can single step the program on your system, as I'm not able to reproduce it (I'm right now at a Linux box).

Comment: @datenwolf: Thanks for your noticed and suggestion too, I still don't know why if `cshader.cpp` is excluded from project then it run fine without any problem :-(

Comment: Edit the contents of those pastebins into the question itself.  Pastebins die, SO doesn't.

Comment: @genpfault: Ok, I have editted my question and emmbded the source code in, now, can you help me?

Comment: I think i found a work around for this: Just build two GLFW library: one for debug and one for release and link my program with appropriate library then it fine, but I still don't know why :-|

Answer (score 0):

I encounted the same problem, but it works now by resolving the following warning.
[How to prevent macro redefinition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927810/how-to-prevent-macro-redefinition)
I hope it works well for you.