# Compile errors when attempting to link <boost\property_tree\json_parser.hpp>

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I have the following "includes" file in my project.

```
#pragma once

//glm
#include <glm\glm.hpp>
#include <glm\ext.hpp>
#include <glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp>

//glew
#include "GL\glew.h"

//glfw
#define GLFW_DLL
#include "GLFW\glfw3.h"

//libpng
#include <png.h>

//std
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>

//boost
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost\property_tree\json_parser.hpp> /* problem */

//mandala
#include "types.h"
#include "type_traits.h"
#include "hash.h"
#include "macros.h"
```

When I include `<boost\property_tree\json_parser.hpp>`, I get many errors indicating that I'm redefining `APIENTRY` such as this one:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\minwindef.h(130): warning C4005: 'APIENTRY' : macro redefinition
```

I'm perplexed as to why this is happening.  I've tried to suppress the `minwindef.h` file from being processed by putting `#define _MINWINDEF_` before the include statement but to no avail.  Has anyone else encountered this or have any idea how I can properly include this boost library?

**NOTE**

Comment: What you quoted there is a *warning*, not an error. But having tons of different headers included at once feels very wrong. Either you are including unnecessary headers, or you are violating the SRP in the class that is implemented in that file. Or both.

Comment: Sorry, I have warnings as errors.  There are also multiple macro defines that cause errors like `minwindef.h` declaring `near` and `far`; names I used extensively in my code.

Comment: So you included something that in turn includes some WinAPI headers. Those define tons of macros, sometimes even more than once in different headers. You never should use those macro names for your own macros or variables. I must confess, it surprises me that the `json_parser` would be the lib that includes those headers rather than the `filesystem` lib.

Comment: @ArneMertz That's what I was thinking as well, I'm really confused as to why a glorified text parser would require the windows API.

Comment: @ArneMertz Your mention of SRP violations got me to move some of the includes to just the places they're used instead of the big include file, I now only have the WINAPI redefinition warning (error) to deal with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent macro redefinition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927810/how-to-prevent-macro-redefinition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since youd did neither update your question to reflect the changes to the includes you made, nor provide the whole warning message, I can only guess:

You still have `glfw.h` included before the boost lib that includes the WinAPI header. Because when I just google for "APIENTRY redefinition", I get [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927810/how-to-prevent-macro-redefinition) as first result, including the answer: Put the WinAPI header (or the boost header includign them) before the `glfw.h` include.

Comment: Moving the glfw includes to only the relevant files solved the problem.  Thank you. :)

Comment: @cmbasnett Lesson to learn from that: please use google before asking on SO. You will often get your answer way faster.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to include also `ptree`.

```
    #include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
```

Comment: And in what way would that remove the includsion of WinAPI headers?